# Database: what design to have a “document table” referencing others tables

Tags: database-design, optimization

I have some tables which can have 0..* documents.

How can I design my data model to avoid having a specific document table for each of my tables? Feel free to suggest by [editing the data model](http://yuml.me/edit/24fab231)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty easy to do this but I wouldn't recommend it.  To implement a single "document" table for all possible documents and parents, you just abstract the id into a "parent_id" column, and add a "parent_table_name" column.

There are a **lot** of issues with this approach.  Some are:

1. Referential Integrity can no longer be enforced by the DBMS.
2. Query expression is now more complex.
3. Surrogate keys of a single numeric type are required for all the parents, even if that isn't the best choice for a given parent.
4. You cannot show the relationships visually on an ERD.  Instead, you now just have table boxes with no lines as there are no enforceable relationships.

The perceived simplicity of a single table with an abstract reference is seductive but ultimately proves to be the opposite of simple due to the above issues.  I think the appeal results from a misapplication of the principle of [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)).  The cohesion here is really between the documents and the entity which they are **about**, not their **structural** similarity in that each table stores a "document."  Applying the principle of cohesion with respect to structure instead of functional meaning can get you into some other ill-advised practices such as [**OTLT** and **EAV**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)).

My recommendation is to stick with the design you already have.  It is correct and doesn't need "improved."

Comment: You suggest a good approach of the problem. I was hoping  some smart design like "party model" or other ones unknown to me in order to fit this needs. Thanks again for your good answer.

Comment: One more time, thanks for your useful answer. But, what do you think about this approach of the problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413534/database-what-design-to-have-a-document-table-referencing-others-tables/32611221#32611221

Comment: That solution is exactly the kind of solution I was recommending you avoid.  The diagram provided there is conceptual and in reality the FK's between the "documentary" table and the child tables cannot be enforced with the RI constraint alone.  This is because the id and not the type is contained child table, and the RI constraint cannot prevent putting the id assigned for type car in the documentary table into say the house table.  This solution reflects a programming and not a data management perspective and this is likely why it was proposed on stackoverflow and not here.